# INNER JOIN and IN clause not returning same counts?

Tags: mysql, sql

More then likely I am not fully understanding the differences between the two. However I am trying to figure out how many people from my optout table are actually in my client table. I tried two different ways and thought they would return the same count...

Method One:

```
Select count(*) from `optout`
    where fname in (Select fname from client)
    and lname in (Select lname from client)
    and state in (Select state from client);
```

Method Two:

```
Select count(*) from `optout` as t1
    join `client` as t2
        on t1.fname = t2.fname
           t1.lname = t2.lname
           t1.state = t2.state;
```

Which way would be the correct way to handle this? Method One returns 5,000+ records and Method Two only returns 258.

Comment: both query are not equivalent. The second query encourage all criteria simultaneously. Take second query as good result set

Comment: Use second one. It will be good

Comment: @Jesuraja, 2nd one is not good; it's the correct one. Per what OP looking for; 1st one is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method two is what you want, since it is counting rows in `optout` that match a single row in `client` on fname, lname, and state.

Method one returns rows in `output` that have fname, lname and state rows which exist in `client`, even if they are spread across multiple different rows in the `client` table.

Comment: Thanks! This explains it clearly. I will also do some more research on the first method.

Answer (score 0):

Method one is only requiring that each of the values exist in the `client` table, not that each value exists on the same row in the `client` table.

Method two ensures that each row has matching values which is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is rather equivalent to

```
Select count(*) from `optout`
where (fname, lname, state) in (select fname, lname, state from client);
```

At least, such syntax should work in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

AS to the answer from Jacek L. 
It is not true that they are equivalent.
IN does distinct and counts only once even if the combination of fname, lname and state appears multiple times in the table Clients. Join will multiply the records from ' output ' in such a case